# Video quality change not reflecting immediately in Kaltura player in iOS

Tags: ios, media-player, kaltura, kaltura-player

I am using Kaltura library to integrate video streaming in my app.
I tried changing the video quality of the video by using the following syntax:

```swift
// player = PlayerController() from Kaltura
player.settings.network.preferredPeakBitRate = desiredBitRate
```

The thing is that the quality is being changed but not immediately. It reflects after some time. Maybe the part of video which has already buffered are showing in the same quality in which they were buffered. And after that, quality is changing. It is confusing for user as it seems the quality is not changing at all when he/she selects the quality.

Please let me if there is a solution!!! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The settings are meant to be set before loading the media - that is, before calling `player.prepare(...)`. Then the player gets them on time and acts accordingly.

If you're doing that but it still doesn't work as expected, please open an issue at https://github.com/kaltura/playkit-ios/issues. Include the video URL, if possible.

As an aside, rather than instantiating `PlayerController` yourself, you should get a `Player` instance from `PlayKitManager.sharedInstance.loadPlayer(...)`.

---

*Full disclosure: I'm the tech lead of the team that develops Kaltura's player.*